# How do I refresh a Visualforce page embedded in a Lightning record page?

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page that sits on the Related tab of a Lightning record page basically displaying rollup fields about the related records:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Opportunity" title="Disbursement Summary" showHeader="true" sidebar="false">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico"/>

<title>Disbursement Summary</title>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS214, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css')}" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
    <div class="vcc">
        <div class="myapp">
            <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock >
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-3 slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Total_Amount_Disbursed_Scheduled__c}" label="Total Disbursements"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.VCC_Percentage__c}" label="VCC Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Number_of_Disbursements__c}" label="Number of Disbursements Made"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.VCC_Bank_Percentage__c}" label="VCC Bank Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Balance_Outstanding__c}" label="Total Balance Outstanding"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Other_Percentage__c}" label="Other Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Loan_Limit_Code__c}" label="Loan Limit Code"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Transmit_via__c}" label="Transmit Via"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" onclick="window.location.href='/apex/DisbursementSummary" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Right now, the refresh button reloads the visualforce page, but it does not update the fields displayed on the page. Is there any way I can have the fields update on the visualforce page without re-loading the entire lightning page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling an action in your refresh button from the standard controller and rerender your form, like:

```
           <apex:form id="theForm">
                <apex:pageBlock >
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-3 slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Total_Amount_Disbursed_Scheduled__c}" label="Total Disbursements"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.VCC_Percentage__c}" label="VCC Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Number_of_Disbursements__c}" label="Number of Disbursements Made"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.VCC_Bank_Percentage__c}" label="VCC Bank Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Balance_Outstanding__c}" label="Total Balance Outstanding"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Other_Percentage__c}" label="Other Percentage"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Loan_Limit_Code__c}" label="Loan Limit Code"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Transmit_via__c}" label="Transmit Via"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!Opportunity.reset}" rerender="theForm"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
```

Comment: {!Opportunity.reset} is not a valid action on the Opportunity standard controller, but using the quicksave action did the trick. Thank you! Here's what my updated command button looks like: `<apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!quicksave}" rerender="theForm" />`